# consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

This is my project structure

```
 myproj
│
├── app1
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── tasks.py

|---gettingstarted
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── settings.py

│   
├── manage.py
|-- Procfile
```

In gettingstarted/settings:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://'
```

In Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --log-file -
worker: celery worker --app=app1.tasks.app
```

In app1/tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import random
import celery
import os

app = celery.Celery('hello')


@app.task
def add(x, y):
   return x + y
```

When I run "celery worker" it gives me:

```
 consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 61] Connection refused.
```

Comment: Celery is trying to connect to the default broker - `rabbitmq` which runs on 5672 port. It seems your broker settings are not being applied.
BTW, redis runs on port 6379.

Comment: Can you try changing `celery.Celery('hello')` to `celery.Celery('gettingstarted')`?

Comment: Change `BROKER_URL` to `CELERY_BROKER_URL` in `settings.py`

Answer (score 2):

You're not configuring celery from your django settings.  To [integrate celery with django](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html), it's best to just follow the guide:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import random
import celery
import os


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'gettingstarted.settings')
app = celery.Celery('hello')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task
def add(x, y):
   return x + y
```

And in settings.py change `BROKER_URL` to `CELERY_BROKER_URL`.

Comment: `CELERY_BROKER_URL` was the missing piece for me